# Склоняется ли аббревиатура ГОСТ?

Tags: аббревиатуры, морфология

По долгу службы пишу тексты, посвященные сертификации продукции. И часто мне попадается аббревиатура ГОСТ, употребляемая в разных падежах. Можно ли ее склонять: ГОСТа, ГОСТу и т. д.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ГОСТ "именованный" (ГОСТ 10546 - 98), то не склоняется, а в остальных случаях допустимо склонять. Что касается официальных бумаг, то надо смотреть ГОСТовские тексты, у меня их под рукой, в отличие от Вас, нет.

Answer (score 7):

Согласно «Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации»  в косвенных падежах ГОСТ  должен был бы иметь наращения падежных окончаний (ГОСТа, ГОСТу и т. д.), поскольку по форме близок инициальным аббревиатурам типа ТАСС, МИД. Однако ГОСТ 1.5—85 «Построение, изложение, оформление и содержание стандартов» (п. 1.4.14) запрещает в тексте стандартов «применять индекс стандарта (ГОСТ, ОСТ, РСТ) без регистрационного номера», а в сочетаниях индекса стандарта с регистрационным номером аббревиатуру ГОСТ употребляет без наращения падежных окончаний. Напр.: ...сталь быстрорежущая Р18 по ГОСТ 19265—73. Поэтому желательно в техн. и науч. лит., во-первых, не употреблять сокращений ГОСТ без регистрационных номеров, во-вторых, в сочетании этого сокращения с регистрационными номерами не наращивать к нему падежных окончаний. Однако в справочных и других изданиях, требующих особой компактности, допустимо взамен полных или частично сокращенных словосочетаний (госстандарты, отраслевой стандарт) употреблять сокращения ГОСТы, ГОСТов.   (А. Э. Мильчин и Л. К. Чельцова "Справочник издателя и автора", 4.8.2. Написание сокращений ГОСТ, ОСТ, РСТ)

Answer (score 3):

В серьёзных текста лучше не склонять, хотя в разговорной речи допустимо. Вообще аббревиатуры, записываемые заглавными буквами, обычно не склоняются. Когда тенденция к склонению перевешивает, переходят на строчные. С ГОСТ('ом) этого пока не происходит.